# Clicking a button with an id but no name with Perl Mechanize

Tags: perl, mechanize

I am trying to click a button with Perl Mechanize, but there are some twists because I am trying to apply the same script to different sites, each of which has the same id attribute for the button, but the forms are not the same number on the page, and the buttons have no name, just an id.

Is there any way to click a button when you only know the id?

Failing that, what is the best way to determine the number of the form that holds a button with a given id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [HTML::Form](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aForm):

```
for my $form ($mech->forms) {
    if $form->find_input('#theid') {
        # this is the one
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I then submitted the form with `$mech->request($form->click());`